# What is *.mem file from ArcGIS server?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-9.3

I’m running ArcGIS Server 9.3.1 on a Windows Server 2008 virtual machine.  I noticed the other day that my C:\ drive was almost full.  I tracked the issue down to  this location “C:\Users\ArcGISSOC\AppData\Local\Temp” on the server.  There are some .mem files that are written everytime a service is accessed.  For the most part they are small, but every now and then one gets written that’s 2GB.  That is causing issues.  I’ve looked on the ESRI site and can’t find a resource to explain these files and what is being written to them.

Can anyone point me to a resource on these files that explains what they are, or have an explanation as to why I’m getting these large files?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both ArcSOC and Geoprocessing use this directory for caching

[image]

When geoprocessing services make use of either Spatial Analyst or Coverage tools, you should change the ArcGISSOC account temporary directory to another folder such as **C:\arcgisserver\temp**. Some of these tools have limitations when writing to a path with more than 100 characters or with spaces. The full path can quickly exceed 100 characters with the directory location, service name, and unique job ID combined.

A scheduled task can be setup to to delete these files overnight - increasing space on the local disk.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to take an educated guess and assume the .mem is basically virtual memory.

In this case I'm guessing it's a memory-mapped (MEM) file which is a segment of virtual memory which is being linked to ArcGIS Server.  Since the Server is a shared resource I'm making that assumption.